# Angular use different view templates based on mobile or desktop

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, user-agent, progressive-web-apps

I am working on an application wherein I need to display different views when the site is opened on desktop or mobile. I have responsive design in place
but I want to use ionic components when the site is viewed on mobile (basically a pwa).
What would be the best approach to display different views on the desktop and mobile?

Currently, I am using a single template with flag which detects browser userAgent and renders the views with simple ngIf like

```
<div *ngIf="isMobile">
     Mobile screen
</div>
<div *ngIf="!isMobile">
      Desktop Screen
</div>
```

Comment: Use CSS media queries. Also don't detect "mobile" you want to detect screen size. [It's worth re-iterating: it's very rarely a good idea to use user agent sniffing. You can almost always find a better, more broadly compatible way to solve your problem!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent)

Comment: @Liam thanks. that was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries to set your body font size in pixels then user EMs and or REMs to size everything else. Make sure to always use FlexBox display in CSS [Here](https://github.com/RichardMaher/Brotkrumen) is an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';
 

@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  
  async resizeScreen(event?) {
   
  if(window.innerHeight==pass screen size)
  {
         console.log('Do mobile work');

  
  }  else if(window.innerHeight<=pass desktop screen size limit)
  {
  console.log('Do desktop work');
  
  }
}
```